# How can I assign custom values to buttons and labels on my tableview?

Tags: ios, xcode-storyboard

In my storyboard I have a tableview with buttons. I want to custom assign float and int value to the button.

I have assigned a label with `players.text= Player.player;`  but I don't know to assign the button with float or int value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to set button `title`,

for int value:

```
[button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", intValue] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

for float value:

```
[button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.1f", floatValue] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```